# cURL Output in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have this curl output where I replace with my id, secret and url. It gives correct response.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Cache-Control:no-cache"   -H "Content-Type:application/json"   --user 'id:secret'   'url'
```

But when I'm trying to write it in php in the following way, it's giving error for invalid cleint. How to rewrite curl from the above output in the same way in php? Thanks!

```
$url = 'https://test.api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials';
$clientId = 'client_id;
$clientSecret = 'secret_id';    
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $clientId . ":" . $clientSecret);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

It's giving error - 'invalid cleint', but when I run it in console, it returns access token. This code is only for access token, not for payment.

Edited: My current code is:

```html
$url ='https://test.api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials';
$clientId = NETELLER_CLIENT_ID;
$clientSecret = NETELLER_CLIENT_SECRET;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($clientId) . ':' . base64_encode($clientSecret),
'Content-Type:application/json'
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_error($curl)) {
curl_close($curl);
throw new \Exception('System error. Can not get neteller token');
}
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: The full error message along with the curl error no. please.

Comment: It's just when copying my code, it's allright.

Comment: How to write curl from first console snippet in php to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to add the credentials as part of the headers.

```
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($clientID . ':' . $clientSecret),
        'Content-Type:application/json'
    );

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: I tried it, but still showing this response: ```string(31) "{
  "error": "invalid_client"
}"```

Comment: Try to add the "Content-Type:application/json " to the header, maybe the webservice doesn't allow requests with different content types than "application/json"

Comment: I tried and still the same response. I'll update my question to show my current code.

Comment: I tried this and still the same, I updated my question with my current code.

Comment: Please encode again the ":" it seem that was mistake that I made. The authentication crendentials should be enclosed: base64_encode($clientID.':'.$clientSecret)

Comment: It's the same. How to write command line request in php so that it will be the same. Command line request returns access token, but when I'm writing it in php , it returns invalid cleint.

Comment: As last approach, try to add the verbosity to the command line curl request and the PHP curl request and see which are the differences. You can add extra verbosity to the PHP curl request with: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

Comment: I'm trying to write this command line curl request using php, but it fails. I don't know where I am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out.

Update:

There are 4 reasons why you may get `{ "error": "invalid_client" }` when trying to run your code.

1. You are using client_id + client_secret from your test account on the production environment or vice versa.
2. Your client_id or client_secret values are wrong.
3. The IP address from which your application is making outgoing requests is not white-listed in your merchant account.
4. You are not sending the Authorization header properly.
5. You missed `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "Cache-Control:no-cache"));` from your code.

Comment: I loogged in my test merchant account to which I made requests and in developer settings Secure IP is enabled and I have: Your merchant account Secure IP Addresses: and here I have list of IP addresses and my IP address in there and when I hover it, it says: You cannot remove your current IP address.

Comment: The command line curl request that you used for test was executed from the same machine that are you using for development (Same IP)?

Comment: Yes, same IP, same machine.When I try command line curl request as I posted in my question, it returns token, but when I try using this php curl code, it returns 'invalid client'.

Comment: From the curl command you are executing, there are two headers you have not added in the PHP curl version. See the point 5 I have just added to my answer.

Comment: This is a common mistake - you need to whitelist the IP in the "API Settings" page, not on the "Merchant account Secure IP Addresses" one.